# Do operation when thread dies

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor, and need to associate workerID with each thread, so when a thread dies, that ID should be removed and when new thread is created that ID should be used. But how do I ensure that the thread died. and perform something.

Can not rely on run method completion, as keepAliveTime is 15 minutes.

**Is there any way to ensure this?**

`ThreadFactory` newThread method is like this :

```
public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(group, r, (new StringBuilder()).append(namePrefix).append(threadNumber.getAndIncrement()).toString(), 0L);
    if(thread.isDaemon())
    {
        thread.setDaemon(false);
    }

    thread.setName((new StringBuilder()).append("Thread name : ").append(name).append(" WorkerId : ").append(getNextWorkerID());
    return thread;
}
```

`getNextWorkerID` returns newxtWorkerID.

Comment: Shouldn't this process be handled by the pool itself?

Comment: It is not I think, or did I miss anything?

Comment: Have you considered extending `Thread` class which could notify interested parties? I think this could serve as an example: http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/listings/MyAppThread.java

Answer (score 1):

How about extending the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with an implementation that keeps a `Map<Runnable, String>` with the values being the workerIDs? You can override `afterExecute(Runnable, Throwable)` and remove the workerID from the `Map` in this method.